# Saving a excel file using Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I've a web service,which used to access a excel file from a root directory(at run time I'm uploading an excel file from the file upload control and saving to project root directory). after i did some changes in the file,then I've to save back to a different folder(out side of the project root folder). if there is any functionality exists to save a file using web service?

Comment: What code do you have thus far.. also look at Microsoft.Interop as well.. there are tons of examples but would like to see what you have tried on your own before expecting others to just give you the answer.. thanks

Comment: What does your web service look like (e.g. what are the methods/ code to access/save the Excel file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a File with a webservice is just the same as saving a file anywhere.

Everything you need will be in the class

```
System.IO.File
```

If you want to modify the excel file you will need to look into the Microsoft 12 (or 14) Interop Library.

However you will need to make sure the appropriate Microsoft dll's are registered. You can do this by just installing microsoft office on the production machine. However the best way would be to find out the exact files needed and register them.

Comment: Thanks Adam. but how can i access the file from the root directory and save it into a different location with different name? this is my code to access the file.   string path = currentPath + @"\ExcelFiles\";
               string[] fileName = Directory.GetFiles(path);

Comment: Now i've a file name and the path. how can i save that into a different folder?

Comment: Use the System.IO.File.Move("sourcefile", "destinationFile");  Also make sure you use the Server.MapPath to get the correct file location.